# Cannot bring up ejabberd after VPS change made by hosting company

Tags: startup, ejabberd

My hosting provider **WebFusion** updated my VPS with security patches late last night.

Since then I cannot start my **ejabberd** instance. I get the following errors, which seem to indicate that the hostname has changed.

```
=ERROR REPORT==== 2010-11-29 23:01:10 ===
E(<0.35.0>:ejabberd_config:278) : Error reading Mnesia database spool files:
The Mnesia database couldn't read the spool file for the table 'acl'.
ejabberd needs read and write access in the directory:
   /var/lib/ejabberd
Maybe the problem is a change in the computer hostname,
or a change in the Erlang node name, which is currently:
   'ejabberd@lvps109-104-93-116'
Check the ejabberd guide for details about changing the
computer hostname or Erlang node name.


=INFO REPORT==== 2010-11-29 23:01:15 ===
application: ejabberd
exited: {bad_return,{{ejabberd_app,start,[normal,[]]},
             {'EXIT',"Error reading Mnesia database"}}}
type: temporary
```

Everything has been working a treat for many months and I have made no changes to the VPS configuration, which is based on **Ubuntu 8.04 LTS** by the way.

I have tried everything I could find on Google w.r.t recovering or migrating mnesia files in this type of scenario, but I cannot seem to get the instance started again. I cannot make a binary backup of the files and clean-slate the system since this relies on getting a running instance up before the backup can be completed. It looks like I am stumped and will have to write-off months of user account registrations.

My hostname does not *appear* to have changed with the patches and reboot that the hosting company performed.  Honestly, I don't really know what hostname ejabberd is expecting but I know it is of the form ejabberd@. Is there a way I can determine this from the existing mnesia data files I wonder?

As for the technical support channels of **WebFusion**? They have told me in no uncertain terms that I am on-my-own and offered no support at all when questioned.

Would appreciate any guidance on how to extract the data from the **mnesia data files** in **/var/lib/ejabberd** and how to recover this or a new installation. I will consider moving to a new host or VPS if I have to.

Very many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up using **ejabberdctl** to get information about the underlying mnesia database.

Then set **ERLANG_NODE** within the file **/etc/defaults/ejabberd** to, in my case, **ejabberd@vps**. Et viola the service came up upon typing **/etc/init.d/ejabberd start**.

Upon startup the process reports failed after a period of 30 seconds. Yet I could access the web management interface and dump the database.

For future use, I shall be deployed to a new **ejabberd+MySQL** cluster and obviously leaving my current VPS provider.

Answer (score 2):

1. Stop ejabberd.

> /etc/init.d/ejabberd stop

2.Kill processes: beam, beam.smp, epmd

> killall ejabberd
>
> killall beam
>
> killall beam.smp
>
> killall epmd

3.Remove the files in /var/lib/ejabberd (Create a backup copy of this folder just in case)

> rm -rf /var/lib/ejabberd/*
>
> rm -rf /var/lib/ejabberd/.erlang.cookie

4.Try to start ejabberd.

> /etc/init.d/ejabberd start